# SQL - Select equal numbers of result of each IN parameter

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I'm building a quiz game app, and I'd like to improve some queries. 
When I launch a game, I have to retrieve some random questions from the database.
Now, when a game is launched, it has a given category for it, and a given number of data to retrieve. The questions in the database used to have a `category_id` attribute.

```
SELECT id 
FROM game_data
WHERE category_id = :category_id
ORDER BY rand()
LIMIT :size
```

But after some changes in the database, questions now have a  `subcategory_id` which belong to a category. So now the queries look like this :

```
SELECT id 
FROM game_data
WHERE subcategory_id IN (:subcategory_id1, :subcategory_id2...)
ORDER BY rand()
LIMIT :size
```

Now my question is the following :
I'd like to retrieve the same number of questions per subcategory in my query.
For example, if I have 18 questions to retrieve and 6 different subcategories, I would have to get 3 questions of each (*the number of subcategories is variable with the categories*).
I've been doing it with multiple queries yet but I haven't found any way of performing that in a single query.

Would any one have an idea about it ? :)

Comment: You could use "union", each subquery for a subcategory and with a limit.

Comment: is it MySQL or MSSQL server ?

Comment: Outside of PhillipD's suggestion, there is not a way to do it in a single query.

Comment: @Uueerdo You can also do it using FIND_IN_SET to simulate Oracle/MSSQL's `partition by`.  It's an ugly way of doing it, and is probably slower, but you CAN do it.  Still waiting for `partition by` in MySQL -- then it would be easy.

Comment: @RobertMcKee, I don't see how a string function would help him partition his LIMIT.

Comment: @Uueerdo This thread would help: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?32,225340,225364#msg-225364

Comment: @Uueerdo Sorry, linked too far down that thread, this one is more appropriate: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?32,225340,225664#msg-225664 Once you can get the result set with a rank, then you can wrap the query, and use `WHERE Rank<=3` instead of `LIMIT`.

Comment: @RobertMcKee, I think I kinda maybe see where you are going with this; but, if I am thinking of it the way you are intending, I could see that having absolutely atrocious performance.. and it probably wouldn't work out right since the RAND() that would be needed in the GROUP_CONCAT would result in a different "ranking" system for each row result.

Comment: @Uueerdo I doubt it would run the GROUP_CONCAT for each row, but performance likely wouldn't be great.  Arth's answer below is likely many times better performance wise.  It was just to show there were other approaches, not necessarily a better one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the union approach you can use something like (shown here for two categories)

```
SELECT * FROM (

SELECT id 
FROM game_data
WHERE category_id = :category_id1
LIMIT :size

UNION ALL

SELECT id 
FROM game_data
WHERE category_id = :category_id2
LIMIT :size
) q1

ORDER BY rand()
```

where :size is the number of questions per subcategory you want to show.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with user variables, something like:

```
SELECT id 
  FROM (
   SELECT id,
          CASE 
            WHEN @sub_cat = subcategory_id THEN @count := @count + 1
            ELSE @count := 0
          END count,
          @sub_cat := subcategory_id sub_cat          
     FROM (
       SELECT *, rand() rand
         FROM game_data
        WHERE subcategory_id IN (:subcategory_id1, :subcategory_id2...)
     ORDER BY subcategory_id, rand
          ) rand
     JOIN (SELECT @sub_cat := NULL, @count := 0) init
       ) pick
 WHERE count < :qu_per_group;
```

See [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/309f8/1)

**N.B.** You'd be a damn site better off filtering by using a category->subcategory relation rather than binding in the subcategory_ids.